# Select options in sencha touch is not working for android

Tags: android, sencha-touch, extjs

I have an application where i am using sencha touch JS API for UI rendering. The UI works fine in chrome browser but not working in Android or iPhone device.

i have used the following code.

```
    Ext.regModel('Contact', {
    fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
});

var store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    model  : 'Contact',
    autoLoad : true,
           autoDestroy : true, 
    data: [
        {firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'},
        {firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'},
        {firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer'},        
        {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
        {firstName: 'Jay',     lastName: 'Robinson'}
    ]
});

new Ext.Application({
    launch: function() {
       var panel =  new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            id:'thePanel',
            layout: 'auto',
            style: 'background-color:darkblue',
            scroll:'vertical'
        });
//do this in your dynamically called function
    var list = new Ext.List({
        id :'theList',
        itemTpl : '{firstName} {lastName}',
        store: store1,
        width: '100%',
        scroll:false
    });

var stateList = new Ext.form.Select({
    label : 'State',
    widht: '100%',
    options: [
        {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
        {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
        {text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}
    ],
    autoLoad : true,
    autoDestroy : true
});

    panel.items.add(list);
    panel.items.add(stateList);
    panel.doLayout();               
    }
});
```

[image: Option list in not populating]

It gives the UI like as shown in the image. But the select control is not working for (State list in not populating). please help me.

Comment: there is a typo in your "stateList" just here or in code too? width not widht.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each form field needs to have a name property, i.e. the name of the parameter to be send when the form is submitted. Updated your stateList object like this:

```
var stateList = new Ext.form.Select({
label : 'State',
name: 'selectField',
width: '100%',
options: [
    {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
    {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
    {text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}
],
autoLoad : true,
autoDestroy : true
```

});