# How to get selected value in Sencha touch option field

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have an select field, on screen. I want to get the selected value, on value change. so i have used the listener to the field. But it is printing only the value, which is nothign but the code for the product. How could i get the product name.

productCodes are : **[{"state1", "state2", "state3"}]**

productNames are **: [{"Alabama", "Alaska", "Colordo"}]**

```
var ProductList = new Ext.form.Select({
    layout: 'form',
    label: 'Product',
    id: 'productList',
    name: 'product',
    widht: '100%',
    labelWidth: '40%',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    store: 'productStore',
    displayField: 'productName',
    valueField: 'productCode',
    listeners: {
        change: function (field, value) {
            console.log("product " + field + ' ' + value);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Guys i made it working using the below code. Anyways thanks.

```
var temp =  field.store.findRecord('productCode', field.getValue());                          
console.dir(temp.data.productName);
```

Comment: can you show me where did you put this code. I am getting error upon error.

Comment: thanks i got it solved it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552571/select-options-in-sencha-touch-is-not-working-for-android?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

In combos use getRawValue() to get the text value displayed, its the value of the TextField input, so it would be ok, cleaner and easier for you to use field.getRawValue().

Hope that helps.

Comment: but it is throwing Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getRawValue'

Comment: Thats, probably, because you not using the correct object, every field (Ext.form.field descendant) has getRawValue() method, are you completelly sure that you tried this in a field Component and not and element?